# DuplicateRecordFields and Function Composition

Tags: haskell

According to [DuplicateRecordFields](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records/OverloadedRecordFields/DuplicateRecordFields#Selectorfunctions) "we can use the type being pushed in to the occurrence of the selector, or a type signature on its argument, to determine the datatype that is meant".

So, the following works<sup>[1](https://gist.github.com/tfausak/e99c867e18f908fb41f29de54bc3501f)</sup>:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
module Records where

data A = A { x :: Bool }
data B = B { x :: Int }

f :: A -> Bool
f = x
```

But this doesn't:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
module Records where

data A = A { x :: Bool }
data B = B { x :: Int }

f :: A -> Bool
f = not . x

{-
  duprecords.hs:9:11: error:
      Ambiguous occurrence `x'
      It could refer to either the field `x',
                               defined at duprecords.hs:6:14
                            or the field `x',
                               defined at duprecords.hs:5:14
-}
```

Why does this break when using a function with the record field? I thought it would still be disambiguated by the function type.

Comment: As chi said, `DuplicateRecordFields` is not up to any nontrivial disambiguation. IMO this extension should never be used – either use plain Haskell98 with explicit module quantifiers, or ad-hoc type classes such as [lens' `makeFields`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html#v:makeFields) generates. When `OverloadedRecordFields` is up running, the record problem will be largely solved; until then, don't fray the language with unidiomatic stuff like `DuplicateRecordFields`.

Comment: just for completeness' sake - [here](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0002-overloaded-record-fields.rst) is the proposal for `OverloadedRecordFields`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the extension is too fragile, unfortunately.

From the docs:

> However, we do not infer the type of the argument to determine the datatype, or have any way of deferring the choice to the constraint solver.

In `f = not . x` the type of the argument of `x` must be inferred, exploiting the type of `(.)` and of `f` (which is provided).

Disambiguating is cumbersome. One has to write

```
f = not . (x :: A -> Bool)
```

or, with `PartialTypeSignatures` on, (& silencing the warning)

```
f = not . (x :: A -> _)
```

Neither is convenient.

Comment: Using type annotation is what I resorted to. Kind of disappointing.